# pygame collisions between sprites

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have searched all over the internet and stack for why my pygame won't move my sprite when it collides with a wall that I have in the game. I have the collision detection loop print out "hit2" whenever the player collides with a wall in `wall_list` (a sprite group). It instead is only detecting that the walls are colliding, by the looks of it, and not when the player collides with the wall. 
Could anyone take a second look at this and tell me what I have done wrong?

```
import pygame, sys
import random
import os
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

len_sprt_x = 21
len_sprt_y = 32 
sprt_rect_x = 5
sprt_rect_y = 160 

SPRT_RECT_X=0
SPRT_RECT_Y=0

LEN_SPRT_X=100
LEN_SPRT_Y=100

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((20, 30)) #Create the screen
sheet = pygame.image.load('/Users/***/Downloads/3KvKpwY.png') 
sheet_chests = pygame.image.load("/Users/***/Downloads/154057568119963649.png")

monsters = pygame.image.load("/Users/****/Downloads/Typhon_Monster-Sire_Sprite.png")
draw_monsters = pygame.transform.scale(monsters, (55, 45))

sheet.set_clip(pygame.Rect(sprt_rect_x, sprt_rect_y, len_sprt_x, len_sprt_y)) 
sheet_chests.set_clip(pygame.Rect(32, 8, 34, 33))
draw_me2 = sheet_chests.subsurface(sheet_chests.get_clip())
draw_me = sheet.subsurface(sheet.get_clip()) #Extract the sprite you want
direction = "none"

class EasyChest(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 425
        self.y = 327
        self.image = pygame.image.load("/Users/***/Downloads/154057568119963649.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class Monster(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = 175
        self.y = 520
        self.image = pygame.image.load("/Users/****/Downloads/Typhon_Monster-Sire_Sprite.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class Monster2(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = 330
        self.y = 400
        self.image = pygame.image.load("/Users/***/Downloads/Typhon_Monster-Sire_Sprite.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class Monster3(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.x = 285
        self.y = 190
        self.image = pygame.image.load("/Users/***/Downloads/Typhon_Monster-Sire_Sprite.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    #direction = "none"
    '''
    Spawn a player
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 450
        self.y = 685
        self.image = pygame.image.load("/Users/***/Downloads/3KvKpwY.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def keys(self):
        '''
        control player movement
        '''
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                print('left')
                direction = "left"
                self.x += -steps
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                print('right')
                direction = "right"
                self.x += steps
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                print('up')
                direction = "up"
                self.y += -steps
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                print('down')
                direction = "down"
                self.y += steps
            print(direction)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord('a'):
                print('left stop')
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord('d'):
                print('right stop')
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == ord('w'):
                print('up stop')
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == ord('s'):
                print('down stop')
            if event.key == ord('q'):
               pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    def update(self, wall_list):
        '''
        Update sprite position
        '''


class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        """ Constructor for the wall that the player can run into. """
        # Call the parent's constructor
        super().__init__()

        # Make a blue wall, of the size specified in the parameters
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(BLUE)

        # Make the top-left corner the passed-in location.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x


mapwidth = 20
mapheight= 30
tilesize = 25


#define colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
TROPICBLUE = (152,245,255)
GREY = (142,142,142)
WOOD = (156,102,31)
PATH = (139,115,85)
GINGER = (255,127,0)
FACE = (238,213,183)
FACESHADE = (205,183,158)
RED1 = (165,42,42)

HAIR = 0
SKIN = 1
NOSE = 2
GRASS = 3
WATER = 4
DEEPWATER = 5
MOUTH = 6
DIRT = 7
PATH = 8

colours = {
    HAIR: GINGER,
    SKIN:FACE,
    NOSE: FACESHADE,
    GRASS: GREEN,
    WATER: TROPICBLUE,
    DEEPWATER: BLUE,
    MOUTH: RED1,
    DIRT: WOOD,
    PATH: PATH
}

tilemap = [
    [DEEPWATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT],
    [DEEPWATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT],
    [DEEPWATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT],
    [DEEPWATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT],
    [DEEPWATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT],
    [DEEPWATER, WATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT],
    [DEEPWATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT],
    [DEEPWATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT],
    [DEEPWATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT],
    [DEEPWATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT],
    [DEEPWATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT],
    [DEEPWATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT],
    [DEEPWATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT],
    [DEEPWATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, PATH, DIRT],
    [DEEPWATER, WATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, PATH, DIRT],
    [DEEPWATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, PATH, DIRT],
    [DEEPWATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, DIRT],
    [DEEPWATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, DIRT],
    [DEEPWATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT],
    [DEEPWATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT],
    [DEEPWATER, DEEPWATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT],
    [DEEPWATER, DEEPWATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT],
    [DEEPWATER, DEEPWATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT],
    [DEEPWATER, DEEPWATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT],
    [DEEPWATER, DEEPWATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT],
    [DEEPWATER, DEEPWATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT],
    [DEEPWATER, DEEPWATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, PATH, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT],
    [DEEPWATER, DEEPWATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH],
    [DEEPWATER, DEEPWATER, WATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH, PATH],
    [DEEPWATER, DEEPWATER, WATER, WATER, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT, DIRT],
]

wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

wall1 = Wall(96, 0, 5, 100)
wall_list.add(wall1)
wall2 = Wall(96, 100, 29, 5)
wall_list.add(wall2)
wall3 = Wall(120, 100, 5, 350)
wall_list.add(wall3)
wall4 = Wall(120, 450, 55, 5)
wall_list.add(wall4)
wall4 = Wall(175, 450, 5, 50)
wall_list.add(wall4)

steps = 5
done = False

monster_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

c1 = EasyChest()
m1 = Monster()
monster_list.add(m1)
m2 = Monster2()
monster_list.add(m2)
m3 = Monster3()
monster_list.add(m3)
p1 = Player()
main = 1

offset_x = p1.rect[0] - p1.rect[0]
offset_y = p1.rect[1] - p1.rect[1]

while main == 1: #game loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  # lets user close the program
            print("UserExit")
            main = 0
    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(p1, wall_list, False):
        print("sprites have collided!")
        print("hit2")
        if direction == "left":
            screen.blit(p1.image, (p1.x, p1.y + steps))
        if direction == "right":
            screen.blit(p1.image, (p1.x, p1.y - steps))
        if direction == "up":
            screen.blit(p1.image, (p1.x - steps, p1.y))
        if direction == "down":
            screen.blit(p1.image, (p1.x, p1.y + steps))

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((mapwidth * tilesize, mapheight * tilesize))
    for row in range(mapheight):
        for column in range(mapwidth):
            backdrop1 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, colours[tilemap[row][column]],
                             (column * tilesize, row * tilesize, tilesize, tilesize))

    backdrop=backdrop1
    print(p1.x, p1.y)
    screen.blit(draw_me, (p1.x, p1.y))
    screen.blit(draw_me2, (c1.x, c1.y))
    screen.blit(draw_monsters, (m1.x, m1.y))
    screen.blit(draw_monsters, (m2.x, m2.y))
    screen.blit(draw_monsters, (m3.x, m3.y))
    wall_list.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
    p1.keys()

    screen.blit(draw_me, (p1.x, p1.y))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to move the `self.rect` of the player because it is used for the collision detection. If you only want to move in integer steps, you can remove the `self.x, self.y` attributes and just use the `self.rect` to store the coordinates.

I've also changed a few more things:

- I'm passing the previous event to the player from the event loop, otherwise the last global event variable would be used all the time. Move the `p1.keys(event)` call into the event loop.
- To reset the position after a collision, you can just move the player back one step.
- I've cleaned up the drawing section of the code (there were two `pygame.display.update()` calls and you blitted the player twice.

---

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """Spawn a player."""
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = draw_me  # Assign the player image.
        # Assign the topleft coords of the rect.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(450, 685))
        # The direction should be an instance attribute not a global variable.
        self.direction = None

    def keys(self, event):
        """Control player movement."""
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key in (pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_a):
                self.direction = "left"
                self.rect.x += -steps
            elif event.key in (pygame.K_RIGHT, pygame.K_d):
                self.direction = "right"
                self.rect.x += steps
            elif event.key in (pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_w):
                self.direction = "up"
                self.rect.y += -steps
            elif event.key in (pygame.K_DOWN, pygame.K_s):
                self.direction = "down"
                self.rect.y += steps
            print(self.direction)
```

The modified main loop:

```
# I added a wall at the start to test the collisions.
wall5 = Wall(420, 670, 50, 5)
wall_list.add(wall5)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # A clock to limit the frame rate.
main = True

while main:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            main = False
        # Pass the previous event to the player in the event loop
        # (once per event not per frame).
        p1.keys(event)

    if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(p1, wall_list, False):
        print("sprites have collided!")
        # Move the player back one step if a collision occurred.
        if p1.direction == "left":
            p1.rect.x += steps
        elif p1.direction == "right":
            p1.rect.x -= steps
        elif p1.direction == "up":
            p1.rect.y += steps
        elif p1.direction == "down":
            p1.rect.y -= steps

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((mapwidth * tilesize, mapheight * tilesize))
    for row in range(mapheight):
        for column in range(mapwidth):
            backdrop1 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, colours[tilemap[row][column]],
                             (column * tilesize, row * tilesize, tilesize, tilesize))

    backdrop = backdrop1
    screen.blit(draw_me2, (c1.x, c1.y))
    screen.blit(draw_monsters, (m1.x, m1.y))
    screen.blit(draw_monsters, (m2.x, m2.y))
    screen.blit(draw_monsters, (m3.x, m3.y))
    wall_list.draw(screen)
    # Blit the player image at the player rect.
    screen.blit(p1.image, p1.rect)
    # Test if the player rect moves correctly.
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), p1.rect, 1)
    pygame.display.update()  # Call `display.update` only once per frame.
    clock.tick(60)  # Limit the frame rate to 60 FPS.
```